# Difference between return statements in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, return

I would like to know the difference between

```
    IF X= 0 
    BEGIN
         RETURN 
    END
```

and

```
    IF X= 0 
    BEGIN
         RETURN 1
    END
```

Which is a better practice when used in a Stored Procedure.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally valid depending on your requirements. If you simply want to exit your procedure then RETURN will suffice.  On the other hand if you want to tell the calling procedure the result of the call then you can do RETURN 1 or any other integer.

More on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx